# cant change FontAwsome icon color

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a problem with an `<i>` element that must be seen only in a media query. The problem is I can see everything works fine in my inspector, but despite `<i>` takes the right font-size, and takes the right space, it doesn't take the color I gave it. The inspector even shows the right color without problems, but the element doesn't take it, it takes the background color of the section, making it impossible to be seen.

The one I want to show in the media query is `id="footer-left-options"`, the other two above not.

[image]

Here some code to help

```css
/*footer-left*/

.footer-section-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-album-cover {
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-album-cover img {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-album-info {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-album-info-artist a {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-album-info-artist a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer-icon-left>i {
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-icon-left>i:hover {
  color: white;
}

#footer-left-options {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 532px) {
  .footer-section-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .footer-album-cover {
    width: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
  }
  .footer-album-info {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .footer-icon-left>i {
    display: none;
  }
  #footer-left-options {
    padding-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!--footer-left-->
<div class="footer-section-left">
  <div class="footer-album-cover">
    <img src="img/sinister.jpeg" alt="Sinister">
  </div>

  <div class="footer-album-info">
    <div class="footer-album-info-title">Sinister</div>
    <div class="footer-album-info-artist">
      <a href="#">Brano nome</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-icon-left">
    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    <i class="far fa-folder"></i>
    <i id="footer-left-options" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add html code here?

Comment: @UdhayTitus oh sorry, I forgot it, I'll post it immediately!

Comment: Assuming that font-awesome is loaded, and your screen is wider than 532px, the icons should be visible (Other than the one with the ID that sets `display: none`). Can you create an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @DBS yes, I've added a screenshot to understand better my problem

Comment: I removed your screenshot from the IDE only showing codelines. Those type of images are unecessary and not helpfull at all. They would require others to type the code from a picture. A stacksnippet should always be used (like it already is)

Comment: @tacoshy ok thanks, I'm new here and I didn't know it, it was posted to help DBS understand because he was asking for an example. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you have a screenshot of what your console shows - I guess that wasn't in the image that @tacoshy removed. Also, what version of fontawesome and what browser are you using? I don't see the ellipsis at all either.

Comment: @AHaworth Hi, sure I've uploaded it now, and yes, it was the picture removed by tacoshy  I take the icon directly from Font Awesome's site https://fontawesome.com/, for the browser I use Brave browser, but I have the same problem even in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox (where instead of not been shown, appears a square with "f141" written inside). The cdn I use is reported in my question code part

Comment: I think there's some sort of mixup between version 4 and version 5. Your script seems to load a version 4 but in the selection of font family it's talking about version 5 (if you look at your console to see the settings for .fas that fontawesome puts in). Which version do you think you are running?

Comment: @AHaworth I tried looking and It says Font Awesome 5, so you think that my CDN is too old and load only until version 4?

Comment: Thanks for putting the image back up. It shows the problem. See near the bottom right it is talking about font family 5, but you are I think loading a version 4 because it isn't using the latest way the FA shows icons (using SVG).

Comment: That should read 'it shows a potential problem' - I still can't get it to work!

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you for the time you take to help me! I've tried checking the link CDN I've put in the <head> but it already covers Font Awesome 5 latest version, so it should include even this one. The other Font Awesome icons I have on the page are version 5 too. Sorry but I haven't understood the meaning of your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the font-weight, since the `<i>` inherited the `font-weight:500` from the previous rule:

```
.footer-icon-left>i {
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks to this site https://www.amp-blogger.com/2019/01/font-awesome-5-not-working-on-css.html I've found the answer. The `<i>` I've token from Font Awesome was this https://fontawesome.com/icons/ellipsis-h?style=solid and opening the link you can see that the icon is described as "solid" and has two pro version both in "regular" and "light" font-weight. Now, since 500 isn't solid (bold), the icon took the color I wanted for it, but didn't display at all! Changing font-weight to `font-weight:800` solves the problem, the icon shows itself regularly and the color is correct.

Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: Thanks to you for have helped me!

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*footer-left*/

.footer-section-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-album-cover {
  width: 50px;
  min-width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-album-cover img {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-album-info {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-album-info-artist a {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-album-info-artist a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer-icon-left>i {
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-icon-left>i:hover {
  color: red;
}

#footer-left-options {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 532px) {
  .footer-section-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .footer-album-cover {
    width: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
  }
  .footer-album-info {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #footer-left-options {
    padding-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f10f36656a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--footer-left-->
<div class="footer-section-left">
  <div class="footer-album-cover">
    <img src="img/sinister.jpeg" alt="Sinister">
  </div>

  <div class="footer-album-info">
    <div class="footer-album-info-title">Sinister</div>
    <div class="footer-album-info-artist">
      <a href="#">Brano nome</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-icon-left">
    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
    <i class="far fa-folder"></i>
    <i id="footer-left-options" class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but I've tried your solutions and it doesn't work for me. I've realized it's a problem with icon, because with other Font Awesome's icon everything works fine